# Conway's Game of Life using Sparse Matrix (Python)

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, conways-game-of-life

I am writing the game of life in python using a Sparse Matrix. My program takes coordinates from user input and sets the cells at the chosen coordinates to be alive. I have it to where it will print the first generation, but I can't seem to figure out why it wont print any subsequent generations. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class SparseLifeGrid:

generations = list()

def __init__(self):
    """
    "pass" just allows this to run w/o crashing.
    Replace it with your own code in each method.
    """
    self._mat = list()
    self.col = []
    self.row = []

def minRange(self):
    """
    Return the minimum row & column as a tuple.
    """
    for i in range(len(self.row)):

        if self.row[i] < self.minRow:
            self.minRow = self.row[i]

        if self.col[i] < self.minCol:
            self.minCol = self.col[i]

    min_Range = [self.minRow,self.minCol]

    return min_Range

def maxRange(self):
    """
    Returns the maximum row & column as a tuple.
    """
    for i in range(len(self.row)):

        if self.row[i] > self.maxRow:
            self.maxRow = self.row[i]

        if self.col[i] > self.maxCol:
            self.maxCol = self.col[i]

    max_Range = [self.maxRow,self.maxCol]

    return max_Range

def configure(self,coordList):
    """
    Set up the initial board position.
    "coordlist" is a list of coordinates to make alive.
    """
   # for i in coordList:
   #     self.setCell(i[0],i[1])

    self._mat = list()
    self.coordList = coordList

    for i in range(len(self.coordList)):
        spot = self.coordList[i]
        self.row += [spot[0]]
        self.col += [spot[1]]
        self._mat += [[self.row[i],self.col[i]]]

    self.maxRow = self.minRow = self.row[0]
    self.maxCol = self.minCol = self.col[0]


def clearCell(self,row, col):
    """
    Set the cell to "dead" (False)
    """
    self[row,col] = 0

def setCell(self,row, col):
    """
    Set the cell to "live" (True") and if necessary, expand the
    minimum or maximum range.
    """
    self[row,col] = 1


def isLiveCell(self,row,col):
    n = len(self.coordList)

    for i in range(n):

        if (self._mat[i] == [row,col]):
            return True

    return False


def numLiveNeighbors(self, row,col):
    """
    Returns the number of live neighbors a cell has.
    """
    neighbors = 0

    if self.isLiveCell(row+1,col): #checks below the current cell
        neighbors += 1

    if self.isLiveCell(row-1,col): #checks above the current cell
        neighbors += 1

    if self.isLiveCell(row,col+1): #checks to the right of the current cell
        neighbors += 1

    if self.isLiveCell(row,col-1): #checks to the left of the current cell
        neighbors += 1

    if self.isLiveCell(row+1,col+1): #checks downwards diagonally to the right of the current cell
        neighbors += 1

    if self.isLiveCell(row+1,col-1): #checks downwards diagonally to the left of the current cell
        neighbors += 1

    if self.isLiveCell(row-1,col+1): #checks upwards diagonally to the right of the current cell
        neighbors += 1

    if self.isLiveCell(row-1,col-1): #checks upawards diagonally to the left of the current cell
        neighbors += 1

    return neighbors


def __getitem__(self,ndxTuple):
    row = ndxTuple[0]
    col = ndxTuple[1]

    if(self.isLiveCell(row,col)==1):
        return 1

    else:
        return 0

def __setitem__(self,ndxTuple, life):
    """
    The possible values are only true or false:
    True says alive, False for dead.
    Also, check to see if this cell is outside of the maximum row and/or
    column. If it is, modify the maximum row and/or maximum column.
    """
    ndx = self._findPosition(ndxTuple[0],ndxTuple[1])

    if ndx != None:

        if life != True:
            self._mat[ndx].value = life

        else:
            self._mat.pop[ndx]

    else:

        if life != True:
            element = _GoLMatrixElement(ndxTuple[0],ndxTuple[1],life)
            self._mat.append(element)

def _findPosition(self,row,col):
    ''' Does a search through the matrix when given the row&col and
        returns the index of the element if found
    '''
    n = len(self._mat)

    for i in range(n):

        if (row == self._mat[i]) and (col == self._mat[i]):
            return i

    return None

def __str__(self):
    """
    Print a column before and after the live cells
    """
    s=""
    maxRange=self.maxRange()
    minRange=self.minRange()

    for i in range(minRange[0]-1,maxRange[0]+2):
        for j in range(minRange[1]-1,maxRange[1]+2):
            s+=" "+str(self[i,j])
        s+="\n"

    return s

def getCopy(self):
    """
    Return a copy of the current board object, including the max and min
    values, etc.
    """
    return SparseLifeGrid()

def evolve(self):
    """
    Save the current state to the "generations" list.
    Based on the current generation, return the next generation state.
    """
    self.generations.append(self._mat)

    for row in range(len(self.row)):
        for col in range(len(self.col)):

            if ((self[row,col] == True) and (self.numLiveNeighbors(row,col) == 2)):
                self.setCell(row,col)

            if ((self[row,col] == True) and (self.numLiveNeighbors(row,col) == 3)):
                self.setCell(row,col)

            if ((self[row,col] == True) and (self.numLiveNeighbors(row,col) < 2)):
                self.clearCell(row,col)

            if ((self[row,col] == True) and (self.numLiveNeighbors(row,col) > 3)):
                self.clearCell(row,col)

            if ((self[row,col] == False) and (self.numLiveNeighbors(row,col) == 3)):
                self.setCell(row,col)

    self.generations.append(self._mat)
    return self._mat

def hasOccurred(self):
    """
    Check whether  this current state has already occured.
    If not, return False.  If true, return which generation number (1-10).
    """
    for i in range(len(self.generations)):

        if len(self.generations) > 0:
            print("This is generation",len(self.generations))
            return self.generations[i]

        else:
            print("No Generations")
            return False

def __eq__(self,other):
    """
    This is good method if we want to compare two sparse matrices.
    You can just use "sparseMatrixA == sparseMatrixB" once this method
    is working.
    """
    pass

class _GoLMatrixElement:
    """
    Storage class for one cell
    """
    def __init__(self,row,col):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.next = None  #
        # Since this node exists, this cell is now alive!
        # To kill it, we just delete this node from the lists.
```

```
from SparseLifeGrid import SparseLifeGrid
import sys

def readPoints(lifeGrid):
    """
    Reads the locations of life and set to the SparseMatrix
    """
    print("1. Enter positions of life with row,col format (e.g., 2,3).")
    print("2. Enter empty line to stop.")

    life=input()
    coordList=[]
    while life:
        points=life.split(",")
        try:
            coord=[int(points[0]),int(points[1])]
            coordList.append(coord)
        except ValueError:
            print("Ignored input:" + life+ ", row, col not valid numbers")
        except:
            print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        print("added, keep entering or enter empty line to stop.")
        life=input()
    print("Thanks, finished entering live cells")
    lifeGrid.configure(coordList)

def main():
    """
    Runs for ten generations if a stable (repeating) state is not found.
    """
    lifeGrid= SparseLifeGrid()
    readPoints(lifeGrid)
    patterns=0
    i=0 
    while i <10 :
        """
        Evolve to the next generation
        """
        lifeGrid.evolve()
        print(lifeGrid)
        """
        Check whether this generation is a repetition of any of the
        previous states.
        If yes return the previous matching generation (1-10).
        """
        patterns=lifeGrid.hasOccurred()
        if patterns != -1:
            break
        i+=1

    if i==10:
        print("No pattern found")
    else:

        print("Pattern found at: " + str(i)+ " of type: " + str(patterns))

main()
```

Comment: Is this your whole code? Where is `printLifeGrid` defined?

Comment: There is not printLifeGrid anymore. I just forgot to take it out of the main. I'll change that on here.

Comment: Why do the things that say "return blah as a tuple" return lists?

Comment: `self.coordList` isn't consistently updated, and you have `pop[ndx]` at one point, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The loop only executes once because of this:

```
patterns=lifeGrid.hasOccurred()
if patterns != -1:
    break
```

`patterns` will never equal -1 under any circumstance, since `hasOccurred` can only return `False` or a member of `self.generations` or `None`. As a result, the loop will always `break` in the first iteration, and no subsequent generations will be printed.

Incidentally, your `hasOccurred` logic is strange. if `len(self.generations)` equals zero, then the loop will not get executed at all, and none of your `return` statements will be evaluated, so the result will be `None`. If the length is greater than zero, then the condition within the loop is always True, so `self.generations[i]` is always returned in the first iteration. Perhaps you meant to do:

```
#changed the name from `hasOcurrence`, since that implies the method can only return True or False.
def get_last_occurrence(self):
    for i in range(len(self.generations)):
        #todo: somehow compare self.generations[i] to the current generation
        if the generations match:
            return i
    #the loop ended without finding a match!
    return False
```

Then, within `main`:

```
patterns=lifeGrid.hasOccurred()
if patterns != False:
    break
```